# Use the ROW function in combination with the range to be worked by the formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

I currently have `=SUBSTITUTE(F10, ",", char(10))`

For the formula to be malleable according to the initial row, instead of the numeral `10` that is next to `F`, I need to use `ROW`.

How to proceed?

Comment: I have updated the spreadsheet to make it more concise.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1K9F8h6LmK2V03YjUc7ZPrIj00bzWcHyULjWZraCqye8/edit?usp=sharing

So you will see in row A it is using =SUBSTITUTE(F5, ",", char(10))

I need the number after the F to say the value of the row it is on. The values in column F will be fed from a different source.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry I did not fully understood your goal. When you use [row()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316) you can input a cell reference to get its row index. example `=row(F5)` will return `5`. I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for since if you use row() inside your formula, it will break your original formula.

Comment: Yeah, thats the issue I am having. I need to figure out how to call that 5 in the formula since it will change per row.

Comment: so basically you want to get the row index of the cell reference used in the formula. the input will be the complete formula and the expected output is the row index right?

Comment: Hi @RickHoward Does this ```=ArrayFormula(SUBSTITUTE(F2:F, ",", CHAR(10)))``` option put on the spreadsheet solve your problem? I don't know who put it, but if it's not the solution, I'll ask you to help me better understand your need, I'm having trouble understanding it.

Comment: @BrondbyIF Unfortunately no, because that still has the same issue of not returning the correct row number when on row 3 or any subsequent rows..

Comment: @RickHoward I will open your spreadsheet and try to understand what result you expect, if I have any questions I ask you.

Comment: @RickHoward Access your spreadsheet please, I'm there waiting for you

Comment: @RickHoward I'm available again, try to help me understand your need, there's something in your explanation that I don't understand because the options in column B and C yield the same result you expect, so what's the problem with them?

Comment: @BrondbyIF I am in the sheet now. Row A is the desired value. B and C were showing the row number but I need it to be like Column A where that value is inside the formula.  F'ROWNUMBER' with commas becomes A'ROWNUMBER' with line breaks.

If not done in Column A then Column F would need to automatically format and remove the commas to become line breaks.

Comment: I will carefully read your comment to try to understand

Comment: @RickHoward I'm there in the spreadsheet waiting for you to help me understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So that you can use a totally malleable formula according to the initial line, let's use the combination `INDIRECT` + `ROW`.

`INDIRECT` gives you the option of handling the range textually and the `ROW` to define the starting line according to the current position.

If you want to use it for a unique and specific line, we will work with:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(INDIRECT("F"&ROW()), ",", char(10))
```

Now in the case of a sequence of lines to be worked on, let's add `ARRAYFORMULA`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(INDIRECT("F"&ROW()&":F"), ",", CHAR(10)))
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I will work with the sequence of lines one to see if it will work as well, there should always be content on each row.

Comment: @RickHoward For that matter of not having value in the rows, no problem, the cell will be without value. If you want to make sure there is no chance of an error appearing, add ```IFERROR()``` to the formula.